# MYSQL - Where x=x And z=z And t=t

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking for the correct way to select values from the MYSQL Tables.

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email 
FROM ps_customer c 
INNER JOIN ps_newsbuild_customer nc 
WHERE c.newsletter = 1 AND 
    c.id_customer = nc.id_customer AND 
    nc.news = 0
```

MYSQL doesn't allow to us the AND operator 2 times in a row.
What is the best way to

```
SELECT value WHERE X=X and Z=Z and T=T
```

When using the following code:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email 
FROM ps_customer c 
INNER JOIN ps_newsbuild_customer nc 
WHERE c.newsletter = 1 AND 
nc.news = 0
```

It works, however it duplicates everything
Example:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [firstname] => John [lastname] => DOE [email] => zz@gmail.com ) 
[1] => Array ( [firstname] => jaimy [lastname] => DOE [email] => tt@skynet.be ) 
[2] => Array ( [firstname] => John [lastname] => DOE [email] => zz@gmail.com ) 
[3] => Array ( [firstname] => jaimy [lastname] => DOE[email] => tt@skynet.be ) )
```

Comment: _"MYSQL doesn't allow to us the AND operator 2 times in a row"_.. said who?

Comment: You are using an `INNER JOIN` without specifying what you want to join `ON`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Using multiple ```AND```'s in a WHERE clause is fine. You're missing the ON clause for your join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your joining criteria of tables in `ON` clause

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email 
FROM ps_customer c 
INNER JOIN ps_newsbuild_customer nc ON c.id_customer = nc.id_customer
WHERE c.newsletter = 1  AND nc.news = 0
```